# TeXStudio and TortoiseSVN

Tags: texstudio, tortoisesvn

I'm guessing that `TortoiseSVN` is the most common Subversion client on Windows. It has a very nice point and click interface integrated into Windows Explorer.

The TeXStudio editor (which we recommend to new users) has build in `svn` support, but I do not think this has been tested with `TortoiseSVN` as it has a rather odd CLI interface and thus the CLI calls that TS is trying to perform to communicate with the SVN server, fails.

Has anyone any ideas as to how one can get TS to work with TortoiseSVN?

Comment: This sounds very much like a feature request rather than a question we can hope to answer. What's wrong with simply installing SlikSVN for command line tools and leaving TortoiseSVN just to handle the shell integration side of things?

Comment: can they work together on the same working copy? I've had problems with that on linux, where I have one svn version on one server and another on a different server. After doing an update on one I could no longer use svn in that working dir on the other server.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this, but I think the important thing is to have the same underlying SVN version in both cases. Certainly the difference between SVN1.6 and SVN1.7 would mean you can't use the two at the same time.

Comment: Exactly my point. Silk is at svn 1.7.7 and tortoise is at 1.7.8

Comment: My more important point was that this is quite possibly something that is hard-coded into TeXStudio and so is not accessible for modification other than by making a request to the developers. (Certainly in terms of Slik one can download older versions: I'd expect Tortoise is the same. So matching versions should be doable.)

Comment: I am not quite clear about what you are asking. Recent versions of TortoiseSVN come with the standard command line SVN binaries as part of the installer package (no need for SlikSVN binaries too), and so if TeXStudio supports svn, it should work with TortoiseSVN. Perhaps you are hoping that TeXStudio can launch the appropriate TortoiseSVN dialogs instead, for which a different CLI is provided? If there are any settings dialogs in TeXStudio for SVN command line tools, then it should be possible (please post screenshots/links). Otherwise, I agree with Joseph that this is a feature request.

Comment: Ahh, found it, that was very well hidden. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @JosephWright I seem to get away with using different versions of svn with the same repository. I think it matters that you not upgrade the repository to the higher of the two versions. (I am using 1.7.something on one machine and 1.8.something on the other.) Though it is a pain not being able to upgrade the repo format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question, remember to ask the `TortoiseSVN` installer to install the standard command line tools.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the TeXstudio user manual, chapter ["Configuring SVN support"](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION08)

> To provide documenten versioning, TeXstudio makes use of SVN (subversion). To make use of it, the SVN commandline tools need to be installed...
>
> The complete path to the command "svn" and "svnadmin" need to be adjusted in the aprioriate field of the svn configure page

SVN-support **is not embedded** into the editor and it can use **any available** (installed) CLI-client, which can be installed with TortoiseSVN 1.7.* or independently.

In the current version the SVN configuration path is not under `SVN` tab, but under `Commands`:

[image: SVN commands]

Comment: of course, the problem was the it is not obvious from TortoiseSVN how to get the cli tools.