# Easy LaTeX Editor with SVN or GIT connection and auto-update

Tags: editors, git, subversion

I've had problems with my current LaTeX editor( Texmaker). It hasn't got an `autosave` option and overwrites the file every time I save them manually .

Is there an editor which has an auto update/save option? Preferably connected to `git` or `svn` so that I can view my old versions as well.

Comment: Have you tried TeXStudio? It supports SVN.

Comment: Is Emacs easy enough? It has built in support for all the main VCSs.

Comment: No is SVN Support native or is it a Plugin?

Comment: I like Emacs, but I fear it will take a lot of time until I've set it up in a way to support latex and SVN/Git

Comment: As I said, support for git and SVN is built in, and there is a basic built-in LaTex mode, not as powerful as AUCTeX, though. You can find the VCS stuff under the Tools menu.

Comment: I think this should be a [tag:big-list] qn and CWed. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-manage-big-lists

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) supports SVN. (See screenshot below.)

[image]

Here are some useful links to deal with SVN and git:

1. [Configuring SVN support](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION08)
2. [TeXStudio and TortoiseSVN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91309/10898)
3. [Using TeXstudio with git](http://alloy2smt.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-texstudio-with-git.html)

Answer (score 4):

Not necessary a `LaTeX` editor *per se*, but if you want to have a bunch of files for which you want to automatically have them commited to `git` at certain defined timepoints, you should take a look at [flashbake](https://web.archive.org/web/20120202215523/http://bitbucketlabs.net/flashbake), which does exactly that. So you could write in your editor and externalize the `autosave` to another piece of software running in the background.

The writer [Cory Doctorow](http://craphound.com/?p=2171) uses `flashbake` to record his writing, including some "meta" data about the process. The project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/commandline/flashbake/wiki).

Comment: I did it but when I try to use I get this error:
"fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

How can I force TexStudio to crate it?