# Using TeXstudio and git to automatically commit using the current date

Tags: texstudio, git

Following up on [Easy LaTeX Editor with SVN or GIT connection and auto-update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155484/easy-latex-editor-with-svn-or-git-connection-and-auto-update), I am trying to set up a way to automatically commit my latest changes with the current date and time (e.g. `-m "autosave on YYYY-MM-DD_hh:mm"`) to a `git` repository using TeXstudio (on Windows).

Using the "Automatically check in after save" feature (see image below) has the following disadvantages:

- Cluttering of the repository (maybe to a lesser extent by saving less often); however, I am aware this is part of the functionality and can hardly be avoided
- The function only commits the file you just saved (even worse, simply adds the current file name to the `svn/git` command).
  If another file was modified (which happens quite a lot if the generated PDF is part of the repository), `git` won't commit the changes.
  Modifying the built-in svn command to something like `git -a` (commit all modified files) fails since a file name is appended to the command, which `git`doesn't allow.
  To clarify, the full command executed looks like this:
  `git -m "my commit message" currentfile.tex`
  I have not yet found a way to **not** append the file name.
- The built-in use of the `%` sign makes it impossible (on a Windows machine, at least) to add system variables such as `%date%`to the commit message

I am not dead-set on using the autosave feature; it would suffice to add a custom command to the standard compilation process.

[image: TexStudio SVN autosave feature]

Comment: I am using a `git` alias for my log output (`l = log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(red)%h%Creset%C(green)%d%Creset %C(white dim)%s%Creset %C(white)%an, %ar%Creset'`, so I immediately see the date my commit was done. Maybe - instead of forcing the commit message - you could use something like this, making your life a bit easier :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem with the following steps:

1. Create a batch file in the directory of your main `*.tex` file
2. Open the batch file and add the following line: `git commit -am "autosave %date%-%time:~0,8%"`. This will commit all changes made (`-a` switch) and set the commit message to e.g. `autosave 2015-08-17-09:34:05`
3. Add a custom command in TeXstudio that executes your batch script (see image below for an example)
   [image: add custom TeXstudio command]
4. Add your custom command to the list of commands for compilation
   [image: add custom command to compilation]
5. After the next compilation of the document, the following message will appear in the message log:
   [image: commit log message]
6. Additionally, the batch file could be modified accordingly to push the changes directly to the remote repository via `git push`

Answer (score 6):

Try to work with git as described [here](http://alloy2smt.blogspot.de/2013/01/using-texstudio-with-git.html) - citated:

Use `git` instead of `svn`. So you have to change the commands for using `git` via `svn`-commands at Options->Configure TeXstudio → Commands → SVN and SVNADMIN to `git`.

[image]

Then open bash and tell git to use the command `ci`:

```
git config --global alias.ci "commit"
```

[image]

There you go. Now you can enable auto-commit at Options → Configure TeXstudio → SVN.

Be advised that these automatic checkins will clutter your repository. It may be a good idea to switch to a different branch before working with TeXstudio and pick/squash the changes to the master branch after you are done.

Comment: I did it but when I try to use it I get this error: "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: works like a charm! @skan did you init a git repository first?

Comment: from TexStudio or from the command line?

Comment: It works fine, but has the small disadvantage that you have to make sure to add all files to git (`git add . `) - otherwise new files you add to your tex project won't be kept under version control.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to commit to GitHub when I found this post, which proved rather useful. =). I guess my answer is a tad late and only elaborates on the solutions already posted a bit beyond the scope of OP's question. However, the issue I was faced with is that the automated timestamp did not work on Linux (Ubuntu 19.10) with the previously posted solutions. Also, adding the script to "Build & View" will create a LOT of commits if you use it frequently. So, personally I came to the conclusion it works better by adding a button/hotkey in TexStudio that can be used to commit.

I found these tutorials for [adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line), and for [Overleaf GIT TexStudio integration](https://github.com/EmaroLab/docs/wiki/LaTeX:-Overleaf-GIT-TexStudio-integration), which I used to set up TexStudio with GitHub. Anyway, I thought I'd add the steps I went through to set up TexStudio with Git and GitHub, with the addition of a timestamp working correctly with Linux.

1. Create a dummy repository on GitHub and find the "Add .gitignore"-button and select "TeX". After creating the repo, download it and copy .gitignore to the folder you want to commit. (This saves you a lot of trouble figuring out which files you need to save and not.)
2. [Set up your GitHub account for use with SSH](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh), if you haven't already. Now create a new, clean GitHub repository, without any adding a README or .gitingore. (Having files already present in my repo created staging problems when I tried to upload.)
3. Follow [the instructions](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line) to set up your repository with GitHub. Set it up with  the SSH-link, as https will create a prompt for username and password every time you try to upload a commit.
4. After this is done, the process of uploading a commit can be automated in a script. Open a text editor in terminal in `/usr/local/bin` as super user. (`Ctrl+Alt+T` to open terminal, then write `sudo gedit /usr/local/bin/gitcommit.sh`). Write something along the lines of:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    git add . 
    # Adds all files in the local repository and stages them for commit (except those defined in .gitignore). 

    git commit -m `date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z"`
    # Commits the tracked changes with the current time in the format "2020-02-15_23:29:56_CET". 

    git push origin master
    # Pushes the changes in your local repository up to the remote repository you specified as the origin
```

5. In TexStudio, under the preferences ("Configure TexStudio", check the Advanced Mode box), in the Build menu add a new user command as in the picture: 
   [image]
6. Go to the Toolbars menu. Find your command under "All menus>Tools>User" and add to "Tools". You can also go to shortcuts and find your command there and add a desired keyboard shortcut. (Now, you could choose to add this command to "Build & View" or compiler by adding the command `txs:///gitcommit.sh`, like @barghest suggests. However, for me that ended up in an unreasonable amount of commits, so I chose not to.)