# Need help with TexStudio macro for calling a shell script

Tags: texstudio, scripts, git

So, I made [this shell script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528628/202807) that can be called from TexStudio, The scripts calls git to add and commit files with the current date, and then push them to GitHub.
I want to improve it's functionality so that I can add a comment and choose which branch I want to commit to. (I based my scripts on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259303/202807) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301105/202807) comment.)

So far I have made the current macro:

```
%SCRIPT
dialog = new UniversalInputDialog()
    dialog.setWindowTitle("Git commit and push")
    dialog.add("add comment", "Comment", "comment")
    dialog.add("master", "Branch", "branch")
if (dialog.exec() != null) {
    comment = dialog.get("comment")
    branch = dialog.get("branch")
    workDir = "/home/user/directory/path/"
    system("sh gitcommitpush.sh " + workDir + "\"" + comment+ " \"" + branch + "\"", workingDirectory="/home/user/directory/path/")
}
```

and a shell script, `gitcommitpush.sh`, I added to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
#!/bin/sh

comment="$1"
branch="$2"
dir="$3"

#First, I set the path to master directory
cd "$3" 

# Then I add all files in the local repository and stages them for commit:
git add .

# Then I want to check if a comment has been added. If only the generic comment "add comment" is unchanged, I want the script to simply commit with the current date as comment. Otherwise, I commits the changes with current date and the comment passed on from the TexStudio macro.

if [ $comment == "add comment" ]
then
git commit -a -m `date "+%d._%B_%Y_%H:%M:%S_%Z"`
else
git commit -a -m `date "+%d._%B_%Y_%H:%M:%S_%Z_$comment"`
fi

# Last I want to push the changes in your local repository up to the specified branch in the remote repository:

git push origin $branch
```

When I try to execute the macro, TexStudio returns the following error message:

```
The specified stdout redirection is not supported: "> "add comment "master"". Please see the manual for details.

Process started: sh gitcommitpush.sh <path to file

/usr/bin/sh: 0: Can't open gitcommitpush.sh

Process exited with error(s)
```

I am unsure why it doesn't work, and could use some help getting the syntax right. Any kind soul here that can help me?

Also, I want to make the macro/script work for all files and directories, so I am trying to find a way to get the macro script to retrieve the path to the main directory, and pass it on to the shell script. Anyone?

Comment: I don't think that this is on-topic here.

Comment: It's related to TexStudio. That is a relevant topic isn't it? My apologies if not. However, I would point out that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259303/202807) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301105/202807) post, with topics related to mine and which I based my work on is posted here.

Comment: Why the comma in `+ "\"",`? I think the argument of `system` should be a single string.

Comment: How to add such a script to a texstudio menu is perhaps a bit relevant (but I have doubts), how to write the script itself not - you are asking about a bash script which should handle git. There is nothing tex related here.

Comment: I don't know how should be the command line for git, but try this one: `system("echo sh gitcommitpush.sh " + workDir + "\"" + comment + " \"" + branch + "\"" + workingDirectory + "=/home/")` after defining `workingDirectory`.

Comment: Also, dont use `<>` in `workDir`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I *am* asking how to add a macro script In TexStudio that can call and pass information to a bash script, not so much the bash script itself. There are already several post in this forum regarding TexStudio macros, some which call bash.

Comment: @Sigur The [user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) provides the following syntax `system(cmd, workingDirectory="")`. I removed the last part, so the line reads `system("echo sh gitcommitpush.sh " + workDir + "\"" + comment+ " \"" + branch + "\"")`. The following message in TexStudio:
```Process started: echo sh gitcommitpush.sh /home/nord06019185/Jobb/thesis/ "add comment "apprentice"

sh gitcommitpush.sh /home/nord06019185/Jobb/thesis/ add comment apprentice

Process exited normally
```
However, there's no changes to my GitHub repo.