# Has TexStudio an integration with git for control version?

Tags: texstudio, revision-control, git, versions

Has TexStudio a kind of integration with `git` or any other software for control version?

**Wanted Feature**: I would like to select a specific `commit` and then compile the code.

I normally do this manually: in one window I manage git and, in another, I compile the Latex code.

Comment: Did you do a google search on it? https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/340

Comment: yes, I have found information [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261341/using-texstudio-and-git-to-automatically-commit-using-the-current-date) and [here](http://alloy2smt.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-texstudio-with-git.html). That's not an integration and, however, it works really really badly. I was looking for some more sofisticated

Comment: As people mention in the issue it might be better to keep git outside the editor and use a dedicated interface for git via an external tool.